# cancel the element's default new line

Tags: html

how to disable the default newline that some HTML elements are createing.

For example:

```
<p> Hello World</p> <p> Welcome to StackOverflow</p>
```

The browser will render that above HTML code, and print two lines of text, one above the other, I would like that the browser will put these two paragraphs side by side. How am i doing that (it is more general than specific to the paragraph element itself)?

My point with the above question is that I want to be able to structure a simple webpage without some elements being rendering one above the other, since i want for example the navigation section to be on the left side and the content section to be to the right of the navigation section.
I know i can do that with CSS (the positioning of the elements), but i am don't have the time to spent nor have the need for the design side of a webpage, all my purpose is to do a simple positioning of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for those kind of elements use span instead of a p tag something like this

```
<span> Hello World</span> <span> Welcome to StackOverflow</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<span>
```

is a more appropriate tag. `<p>` tags are considered 'block-level' elements, whilst a `<span>` tag is considered 'inline'.

[Inline vs. Block](http://cat.xula.edu/tutorials/html/versus.php) takes a very quick look at the difference between the two.

And as a sidenote: inline elements generally go inside block elements, whilst block elements generally do not go inside inline elements.

### However...

If you really did want to do this, using `<p>`, you can set a CSS style of `display:inline;` which will force the browser to render it as an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
```

is a block-level element. This means it displays like a block, taking up all space in its container. You should be using non-block-level elements like the

```
<span>
```

element